# firebase rules - Error saving rules – Line 2: Expected '"'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Error saving rules – Line 2: Expected '"'.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": true
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help, I really can't see where I'm missing a " on line 2?

Answer (score 1):

I get a different error on those exact rules:

> Error saving rules - Line 5: Expected ',' or '}'.

You need a comma after `".read": true"`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I even tried that, and it wouldn't eat it. But now it works! :D xD But thanks! :D Super weird.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. So I noticed that it happens whenever i copy rules elsewhere and then paste them in firebase. I also noticed that the copied quotation marks from Word, were different from the ones in firebase. So I deleted the quotation marks and retype them and it worked.

I have attached a screenshot to show the differences between the quotation marks. Hope that is helpful.[Firebase rules screenshot to solve Error saving rules - Line 2: Expected ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl42f.jpg)